# How to implement Parentheses Latex Citation format?

Tags: latex, bibliography

I am looking for a specific citation format for Latex but I am not sure how can I implement it. My University wants to see the citations as below:

```
In text (Beatty & Lucero-Wagoner, 2000)

Beatty, J., & Lucero-Wagoner, B. (2000). The pupillary system. In J. T. Cacioppo, L. G.
Tassinary, & G. G. Berntson (Eds.), Handbook of Psychophysiology (pp. 142-
162). New York: Cambridge University Press.
```

What is this format, how can I implement it, which `bibliographystyle` I should use?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

in text \parencite{knuth:ct}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

(note that you have to compile with `biber your_file_name` instead of `bibtex`)

Answer (score 0):

Check out `\citep` from the [natbib package](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf).

You might also ask future questions in the [TeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).